# Best way to set a reoccurring android task

Tags: android, multithreading, timer

I am creating the following thread in my onCreate but realized that this call needs to execute every 20 minutes or so:

```
 Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run(){
       setTopUsers();
    }
  };

  t.start();

 private void setTopUsers() {
    ...

    for(Map.Entry<Double,String> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
           key = entry.getKey();
           value = entry.getValue();

           if(...)
              view.setText(...)
       }
}
```

The method that's being called simply processes information from a TreeMap and displays the results to the UI. I'm trying to figure out what is the best way to handle this: 1) Create a Timer that runs on a separate thread (but I've read that's not a good idea), 2) Create a service Intent that processes every 20 minutes (seems like overkill).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProcessService.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
am.cancel(pIntent);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), INTERVAL, pIntent);
```

Comment: thanks for the details (this is described in the first response)

Answer (score 0):

Let the user decide. Implement both, there's nothing worse than a repeating process the user can't control.